# Find element by Class with Basic Selenium

Tags: html, vba, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to fill a phone number in a web portal, using Selenium for VBA.

Selenium can't find the Text box even when the element has loaded.

My Code

```
Dim ch As Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub FillPhoneNumbers()
Set ch = New Selenium.ChromeDriver

ch.Start
ch.Get "https://nestlemedconnect.com/p/38ZX1SBcKhI"

ch.FindElementByClass("checkbox_label").Click
ch.FindElementByClass("accept_button").Click
ch.FindElementByCss(".left_button_inner.generic_menu_button.ti-comments-smiley").Click
ch.Wait (30)
ch.FindElementByClass("phonemask").SendKeys "122525" ' <- line that errors
End Sub
```

The element I am trying to find.

```
<input class="phonemask" type="tel" name="phoneNumber" autocomplete="off" data-intl-tel-input-id="0" style="padding-left: 74px;" placeholder="201-555-0123">
```

I tried using the name. I get is a Web driver can't find element error.

Comment: Try adding a `Click`  and then `SendKeys`. I guess after a click the field should be able to accept an input

Comment: the problem is that is not finding the element, it does not even  get to try to send the Keys.

Just to be sure i did check adding the Click did not help, it still could not find the element

Answer (score 0):

Cause you need to click on this web element first **Opt-out from SMS**

```
div.ui.bottom.attached.button.optout.triggerform
```

do this :

```
ch.FindElementByCss("div.ui.bottom.attached.button.optout.triggerform").Click
ch.Wait (30)
ch.FindElementByClass("phonemask").SendKeys "122525
```

Comment: `ch.FindElementByCss("div.ui.bottom.attached.button.optout.triggerform").Click`

This Line gives me the same error as before, Element not found

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:-

```
ch.FindElementByXPath(".//div[@title='Manage your subscription']/div[contains(@class,'smiley')]").Click
```

Phone number text field is inside an iframe, so switch to the iframe first before accessing the element as

```
ch.SwitchToFrame.FindElementByXPath(".//iframe[contains(@src,'unsubscribe')]")
ch.FindElementByXPath(".//input[@name='phoneNumber']").SendKeys "1234567890"
```

Comment: `ch.FindelementByXPath(".//input[@name='phoneNumber']").SendKeys "1234567890"`

This line Errors, i can swich frame but it still cant find the element

Comment: `ch.FindElementByXPath(".//div[@title='Manage your subscription']/div[contains(@class,'smiley')]").Click
`
First Line no error Works Fine.

`ch.SwitchToFrame.FindElementByXPath(".//iframe[contains(@src,'unsubscribe')]")` The Second Line gives me an "Argument not optional" Error.

I tried Changing it to 

`ch.SwitchToFrame(".//iframe[contains(@src,'unsubscribe')]")`

But it tells me it cant find the Frame

And the  `ch.FindElementByXPath(".//input[@name='phoneNumber']").SendKeys "1234567890"`  gives me the Cant find Element error

Comment: Can you try adding wait time after you click on Manage your subscription smiley button. Reason is it takes few seconds to load the page completely.

Comment: ive tried that adding up to 40 seconds, i also normally test with the debug mode, menaing the page has all the time in the world to load.

Like i let the page load completly and then i try line by line seeing where it gets problems